# How to get the value of form fields from controller Rails on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, form-for

On Project new view I have a form with text_field

```
  <%= form_for @project do |f| %>

    <h4>
                    <label for = "projectName">Title(required)</label>

                    <%= f.text_field :projectName, :maxlength => 50 %>
                </h4>
<%end%>
```

I am trying to get the values on controller by,

```
params[:projectName]
```

But I always get nil on my logs for this

**Note**

My project resides in com/a/b/c/project

Therefore I tried calling

```
params[:com_a_b_c_projectName]
```

Still get nil on my logs

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try `params[:project][:projectName]`

Comment: Also, I would recommend putting `binding.pry` in the controller and you will see all the params instantly.

Comment: first you should stop using `params[:com_a_b_c_projectName]` and set up the `form_for` code correctly as my answer (and the Rails Guides) on your other question indicates :) getting that out of the way will help set the foundation right, so to speak, before trying to address further problems

Comment: @PetrGazarov params[:project][:projectName] still gives me nil

Comment: @sixty4bit I tried setting path as you said but it kept throwing me undefined method `com_a_b_c_com_a_b_c_projects_path' for #<#<Class:0x9238530>:0x922d7d8>   path error :( I also updated my    params params.require(:project).permit(:projectName, :briefDesc, :whatSection, :challengers, :status, :valueProposal, :maturityLevel,:tag_ids =>[])#tag_ids: []

Comment: @Newbie if you're doing it the way the RailsGuides say and getting errors, you should try to find out why :) because you're doing it wrong. notice how everything in that path seems doubled for some reason

Answer (score 0):

the rails convention is, it automatically wrap the params in form. so it should be `params[:project][:projectName]`.
read details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) in chapter 7.1

Comment: can you provide your server logs for the specific request? something looks like this `Started GET "/tests/new" for ::1 at 2016-04-07 23:43:03 -0400
Processing by TestsController#new as HTML
  Rendered tests/_form.html.erb (7.8ms)
  Rendered tests/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 34.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 4 or above then make sure `params.require` is set in the controller to accept parameters from view.

Once it's set you can find the params in `params[:project][:projectName]`. Also make a submit button (`<%= f.submit %>`) to submit the params in controller.